# Interaction between git client and local file system

Tags: git, filesystems

I'm running git bash client on my Windows machine and I use it to clone all branches of a remote repo into a directory named "localRepo" on my Windows machine. The repo has two branches ("master" and "develop") and I start out on branch "master".

When I open "localRepo" in Windows File Explorer, I see the .git sub-directory and various files and sub-directories of that branch.

When I go to the git client command line and checkout branch "develop", does the git client manipulate the Windows file system so that I would then see the files on branch "develop" when I go to "localRepo" in Windows File Explorer?

I assume git is keeping the state of all branches in the .git directory.

Is git creating symbolic links that it switches when branches are changed?

Comment: What's the meaning of `I see the .git sub-directory and various files and sub-directories of that branch.` ? your `branch` means what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, after `git checkout develop`, GIT will physically update your localRepo Windows folder with files from the develop branch. Just try it and you will see.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two branches, your case is `master` and `develop` in your local repo. 
At first you should know the work directory are branches shared.

If you in the `dev` branch you add a `a.txt`, and type content `a`, but you did not add the `a.txt` to the stage, then you checkout to the `master` branch. you can see `a.txt` and its content, because the `a.txt` has no relation to both branches.

If you add the `a.txt` to stage, and commit it to master in `dev` branch, then you checkout to master, you can not see the `a.txt`, because the `a.txt` is in control of git now, your conjecture is correct, the git will update the repo directory base on branch. If you want to in the master branch own the `a.txt`, just merge the `dev` branch in master.

About your:

> Is git creating symbolic links that it switches when branches are changed?

Yes, the git destined to trace it, you can open the `.git/HEAD` file, if in the master branch it shows:

```
ref: refs/heads/master
```

If you checkout to other branch, you can see the significant change.